# multicolumn table with different \sisetup{} settings

Tags: tables

I am wondering if there is a way to use different parameters of \sisetup{} for each column of a table. For instance, I would like to use:

```
\sisetup{round-mode=places,
round-precision=2,
fixed-exponent = 6,
scientific-notation = fixed,
}
```

for the first column of my table and a slightly different version of it:

```
\sisetup{round-mode=places,
round-precision=2,
fixed-exponent = 8,
scientific-notation = fixed,
}
```

for the second column of the latter.

Ex:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\sisetup{round-mode=places,
round-precision=2,
fixed-exponent = 6,
scientific-notation = fixed,
}
\sisetup{round-mode=places,
round-precision=2,
fixed-exponent = 8,
scientific-notation = fixed,
}
\begin{tabular}{SSS}
\hline A & a & b \\ \hline
$B$ & -8940513.51965462 & -393467529.743240\\
$C$ & -8295841.85412406 & -365095852.079073 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

You can split `sisetup` on two parts:

- common (global), which settings are used in all `S` columns
- local, where you can add or overwrite common settings where is needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}   % added
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{round-mode=places,  % common settings
         round-precision=2,
         fixed-exponent = 6,
         scientific-notation = fixed,
         }
\begin{tabular}{l S[fixed-exponent = 8] % <--- local
                  S}
    \toprule
A   &  {a}              & {b}               \\ 
    \midrule
$B$ & -8940513.51965462 & -393467529.743240 \\
$C$ & -8295841.85412406 & -365095852.079073 \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Zarko. That perfectly answers my question. Kind regards.

Comment: @Mary, now you can upvote and even accept answer (by clicking on up-triangle and check mark at top left side of answer)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use some common settings for the whole table and some local ones for the specific column. You also want to specify the number of digits, so the headers will be placed correctly and the spacing is optimal. Of course such a setting will be done *a posteriori*, after looking at what the table actually produces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]

% common settings for this table
\sisetup{
  round-mode=places,
  round-precision=2,
  scientific-notation = fixed,
}

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[fixed-exponent = 8,table-format=-1.2e1]
  S[fixed-exponent = 6,table-format=-3.2e1]
}
\toprule
A   &  {a}              & {b}               \\ 
\midrule
$B$ & -8940513.51965462 & -393467529.743240 \\
$C$ & -8295841.85412406 & -365095852.079073 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]